# How to pass a method as an argument in AlpineJS?

Tags: alpine.js

How can I dynamically call a method from another in AlpineJS? In the example below, foo() should call bar() to run the method it receives. This doesn't work, because 'Uncaught TypeError: callback is not a function'.

```
foo(){
  bar(this.baz())
},
bar(method){
  method()
},
baz(){
  return 'success'
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you're not passing the method, you're passing the output for the method call, try

```js
foo(){
  bar(this.baz)
},
bar(method){
  method()
},
baz(){
  return 'success'
}
```

If you get issues with `this` in `baz` you might need to do:

```js
foo(){
  bar(this.baz.bind(this))
},
```

Comment: Thanks. The reason I didn't even try leaving the parentheses, was that I had to pass on an argument for the method. I now solved it like this:

foo(){
 this.bar({method: this.baz, argument: 'success'})
},
bar(args){
 m = args.method
 arg = args.argument
 m(arg)
}